# Matlab: Please check my code for Reading data from a File and Saving it as an array into a variable

Tags: matlab

I am very new to Matlab so I would like to request you to look into my code. I want to copy data in my 'Data.raw' file (4 numerical values in each line separated by a space ) into a TSOutput (n x 4 matrix). On running my program, the variable TSOutput has values only in the first column and some values from the are missing. Please check my code. Thank you.

```
fileID = fopen('Data.raw');
TSOutput = textscan(fileID,'%f,%f,%f,%f/n' );

while not(feof(fileID))
    readData = textscan(fileID,'%f,%f,%f,%f/n');
    
    if feof(fileID)
        break;
    end
    
    TSOutput = [TSOutput; readData];
end

disp(TSOutput);
fclose(fileID);
```

Data in the Data.raw file looks like this:

```
1 1 0 -6.291667
1 1.003333 0 -0.2748109
1 1.003333 0.1 -0.2748109
1 1 0.1 -6.291667
1 1.006667 0 0.8322136
1 1.006667 0.1 0.8322136
1 1.01 0 1.501634
1 1.01 0.1 1.501634
```

These are just a few lines. There are many lines of these data.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: ask your question in question form. "Check my code" is not a question. Tell people what's wrong. So they won't spend time reading your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am new and I am sorry if I caused trouble. I tried writing a question but it seemed that it had already been asked. I checked the available answer to those questions but the code was very different from what I was using so I resorted to the above question so I could post it. I'll make sure I post a proper question next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It seems I just had to remove the [,] and replace it with a space mark for the two lines below.

```
TSOutput = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f/n' );

    readData = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f/n');
```

and it worked like a charm.